# Disproportionate window pane font size compare to the emails

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a user who is dealing with an odd issue. Their Outlook has disproportionate folder pane and ribbon fonts compared to the text that is within the emails themselves (i.e. the list of emails and the reading panes). The fonts there are larger than usual:

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone have any idea why?

The user said they had made no changes, and that this has been going on for a few days now. They do have two monitors and one is upscaled to 125%, but it appears the same on both screens and changing the scaling back has not remedied the issue. (Nor has messing with different scaling or changing resolutions).

Is the upscaled monitor possibly screwing with things?

If it helps, both screen resolutions are 1280 x 1024.

Comment: They have turned off their reading pane from what I see... Enabling it should fix it.

Comment: We had some new Dell laptops with the same issue. You need to turn off all the accessibility and scaling options, then reboot. There was also a windows update that added the option 'fix fuzzy text' which seemed to help.

Comment: Maybe we can refer to some of the settings in this link：https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/fontsizecolor.htm#reading_pane